# Correct coordinates in Animation with Translate in Android

Tags: android, image, animation

I have a XML to move an image from below right to up right as shown in the pictures and the reverse.

[image]
[image]

My problem is that I can not find the exact coordinates to achieve this.

**up.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:fillAfter="true">

    <translate
         android:fromYDelta="0%p"
         android:duration="800" 
         android:toXDelta="60%p"/>
</set>
```

**above.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:fillAfter="true">

    <translate
         android:fromYDelta="60%p"
         android:duration="800" 
         android:toXDelta="0%p"/>
</set>
```

I could help someone telling me which is correct? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I've solved my problem:

**up.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
android:fillAfter="true">

<translate
    android:duration="800"
    android:fromXDelta="0%p"
    android:toYDelta="-60%p" />
</set>
```

**above.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
android:fillAfter="true">

<translate
    android:duration="800"
    android:fromYDelta="-60%p"
    android:toXDelta="0%p" />
</set>
```